# How do I adjust my popover to the size of the content in my tableview in swift?

Tags: uitableview, swift, resize, popover

I'm using `popoverPresentationController` to show my popover. The `UITableViewController` used to show as popover is created programmatically and will usually contain 1 to 5 rows. How do I set up this popover to adjust the size to the content of the tableview?

Code for my popover:

```
if recognizer.state == .Began {
    let translation = recognizer.locationInView(view)

    // Create popoverViewController
    var popoverViewController = UITableViewController()
    popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    popoverViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.popupColor()

    // Settings for the popover
    let popover = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.delegate = self
    popover.sourceView = self.view
    popover.sourceRect = CGRect(x: translation.x, y: translation.y, width: 0, height: 0)
    popover.backgroundColor = UIColor.popupColor()

    presentViewController(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Checkout the [preferredContentSize property of UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/preferredContentSize):

```
let height = yourDataArray.count * Int(popOverViewController.tableView.rowHeight)
popOverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: height)
```

Comment: thanks, quite simpel. I tried `preferredContentSize` before but didn't think of using the count of my array :o. When I use this solution, it only works after I've accessed `popoverViewController.tableView.rowHeight` first or else the count and height will just return `0`. How can I do this without accessing the height first?

Comment: I usually set `tableview.rowHeight = 44` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This assumes a fixed row height, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 48):

In your UITableViewController's `viewDidLoad()` you can add an observer:

```
self.tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

Then add this method:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    self.preferredContentSize = tableView.contentSize
}
```

Lastly, in `viewDidDisappear()`, make sure you remove the observer:

```
tableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
```

This way the popover will automatically adjust size to fit the content, whenever it is loaded, or changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adrian and Bo.  I want to disable popover's animation when it is resizing.  How can I dot that?

Comment: @AdityaShinde Please ask this as another question

Comment: I feel uncomfortable overriding the `observeValue` method. Adding the super method crashes...shouldn't there be a better way to observe changes?

Comment: @Trev14 `observeValue` is actually a super common way of observing changes for a key path. You shouldn't be calling super at all. It's extremely rare to call super in that method. BTW, this answer is much better than the others since it doesn't require a manual calculation.

Comment: ah, much better than any other solutions. Too bad RXSwift doesn't have an observable for that. And I'm too lazy to write my own right now.

Comment: You should add it in you `viewWillAppear` if you remove it in the `viewDidDisappear`. Moreover, you also should use a not nil context.

Answer (score 20):

Override the `preferredContentSize` property in your extension of the `uitableviewcontroller` as following:

```
override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        let height = calculate the height here....
        return CGSize(width: super.preferredContentSize.width, height: height)
    }
    set { super.preferredContentSize = newValue }
}
```

For calculating the height check out `tableView.rectForSection(<#section: Int#>)`

Comment: This is getting called before rows get added to my table, so `rectForSection` has a height of zero.

Comment: Any way to do this and maintain size class? Setting this property on iPad is causing me to see my iPhone layout.

Answer (score 14):

Simple dynamic answer for **Swift 4.x** and **Swift 5.x** involving no size-computation (modern version of Bo Frese answer):

```
private var contentSizeObserver : NSKeyValueObservation?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    contentSizeObserver = tableView.observe(\.contentSize) { [weak self] tableView, _ in
        self?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: tableView.contentSize.height) // Here I fixed the width but you can do whatever you want
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    contentSizeObserver?.invalidate()
    contentSizeObserver = nil
}
```

Comment: you saved my life!!

Comment: ⚠️ ⚠️ ⚠️ UI Handling into KVO completion block should be run on Main Queue. I edited the sample above.

Comment: Hello @AntoineRucquoy, in fact, you don't need to run it on the main queue, because it's already running onto it. In fact the KVO handler is run on the queue performing the modification. As the observed property, here `\.contentSize`, is updated only on the main thread (by calling `updateData` and friends) you are sure your handler will be executed on the main thread.

Comment: Hello @Zaphod, I had crashes while displaying my ViewController (where I'm using KVO on the contentSize's UITableView) into a forced popover on a mobile device (not an iPad, strangely). Maybe this is purely depending on how is my project built. However, I still assume that this is always safer to perform UI changes on the main thread.

Comment: @AntoineRucquoy I agree, it's always safer. But it seems the problem you are facing is just a symptom and you just hide it when you fix it by forcing the call on the main thread. You should check why your content size is not updated from the main thread in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

For swift 4 if you want to observe the content size I found this to be the optimal solution. Reporting it here since I did not find a complete example online:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var kvoContext = 0

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(tableView.contentSize), options: .new, context: &kvoContext)

    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(tableView.contentSize))
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if context == &kvoContext, keyPath == #keyPath(tableView.contentSize),
            let contentSize = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CGSize  {
            self.popoverPresentationController?.presentedViewController.preferredContentSize = contentSize
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: All comments are good and help full.
I have did little change in my logic which makes my VC as reusable component.

Calling this method inside `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`:

```
-(void) setPopOverPreferedContentHeight {

     if (self.popoverPresentationController && self.tableView.contentSize.height < MAX_POPOVER_HEIGHT) {
          self.preferredContentSize=self.tableView.contentSize;
     } else if (self.popoverPresentationController){
         self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.contentSize.width, MAX_POPOVER_HEIGHT);
   }
}
```