# iOS 10 popoverPresentationController is nil in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to center a popover in my iOS 10 ipad application.

I have created a popover segue from one view to another in my storyboard.  I have set the 'Kind' of segue to 'Popover':

[image]

Then in prepareForSegue:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PopoverSegue"]) {
  UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverController = segue.destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController;
  popoverController.sourceView = self.view;
  popoverController.sourceRect = self.view.bounds;
}
```

However popoverController is nil.  Looking around it looks like others had success doing this:

[How to change the size of a popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335147/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-popover)

Any ideas why I cannot get a hold of the popoverPresentationController in prepareForSegue when the popover segue was created in a storyboard?

Comment: I do not know your architecture, but it can be that missing navaigationController. Try this: segue.destinationViewController.navigationController.popoverPresentationController or segue.destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController.navigationController

Comment: I don't embed my viewcontroller in a navigation controller.  So there is no navigation controller.  As far as I understand the popoverPresentationController should be in the view that is embedded in the popover.  Just for fun I embedded my view in a navigation controller to see if that made a difference, which it did not.  Bug in iOS 10?  Not supported in iOS 10?

Answer (score 0):

Your segue `kind` is *Popover*. If you changed it to *Present as Popover*, then you should see value in `destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController` property. You may need to explicitly enable trait variations in the storyboard properties for *Present as Popover* to show up as an option.