# Change the height of the popover

Tags: swift, popover

I want to change the height of the popover, I follow every instruction but I got an error that i don't know how to fix that

here is a part of my code

```
class PatientRecordingsViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

...inside a clouser

          let vc = EnteringNoteView()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

        if let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController {
           popover.delegate = self
           popover.sourceView = self?.addNoteViewModel
           popover.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
           self?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In the line of `popover.preferredContentSize` I get this error:

```
Cannot assign to property: 'preferredContentSize' is immutable
Add explicit 'self.' to refer to mutable property of 'TaskViewController'
```

When I tap on the fix ,it adds `.self`:

```
popover.self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
```

Then it shows the same error again. 
I will be appreciated if anyone can help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the size of a popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335147/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-popover)

Comment: Yes dear Joakim, I can't thank you enough